# Sum of powers - how to solve $\sum_{r=1}^{10} 4^r$

Tags: summation, geometric-progressions

How do you calculate sums such as $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{10} 4^r$?

I know how to calculate geometric/arithmetic progressions, but I'm not quite sure how to calculate such 'power' sums using either of those.

Comment: By 'solve' do you mean 'calculate'?

Comment: That sum **is** the sum of a geometric progression; the first term is $4$, the ratio is $\dfrac{4^{r+1}}{4^r}=4$, and the last term is $4^{10}$. Can you calculate it now?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I derped..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $x \neq 1$ we know $$x^{n+1}-1 = (x-1)(x^n + x^{n-1} + \ldots + 1).$$ So
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}
$$
Now since your sum starts at $4^1$ not $4^0$, you need to subtract $1$ in this case to see that $$\sum_{k=1}^{10} 4^k = (4^{11}-1)/(4-1) - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Take this general formula

$$\sum_{r=p}^q x^r=x^p\frac{x^{q-p+1}-1}{x-1},\quad \forall x\ne1$$